# Laravel different environment git .env Xampp & Mamp

Tags: php, git, laravel, github, laravel-5.1

i'm using github in combination with laraval for the first time.

I have 2 local environments :

- a) i use MAMP Pro for local development (Mac)
- b) i use XAMPP for local development (Windows)

I made a new repository and pushed to github on environment a) , I cloned this repository on setup b) and added a .env file to setup my database. However i'm a bit confused what to do with the app_key value, do i need to just copy it form my initial environment? or need a new one?.

**The second part** of my question is that i seem to have problems with xampp vs mamp pro because they rewrite a couple of urls, wich means my project won't run on environment b). Are there other settings i need to adjust? and will it brake again if i commit on environment b) ?

Error message when running the project on environment b)

```
Warning: require(D:\dev.local\ADifferentDesign\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\dev.local\ADifferentDesign\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\dev.local\ADifferentDesign\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\dev.local\ADifferentDesign\bootstrap\autoload.p
```

I'm really confused , i saw other questions like this but none are quite what i was looking for.

A good aproach for future projects would also be very much appreciated

**Progress update 1**: I updated my .env file with the same key. But the error shown above still persists. I dont want to change te path in autoload every time i switch environments either.

Comment: Yes, you need to generate a key for each environment. Move to homestead.

Comment: ok i will generate a seperate key, moving to homestead doenst really answer my question, if it's possible i rather not have to do that

Comment: You don't have to move to homestead.

Comment: i have moddified my .env file , but the error shown in the second part of my question still persist and i really don't want to branch just for the other environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you are sharing any resources that hold encrypted data between the two environments, like a database, then you must copy the `app_key`. This is because Laravel uses the `app_key` whenever it encrypts something like a user's password or a session ID.

If you don't need to share a database, sessions, etc then you can **and should** generate a new key for every environment.

You generate a new key by running this command in your site root:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Ideally, you would run this command as the first step in setting up a new environment, before running database seeds or other stuff. This is because if you generate a new key after seeding your database then any password you created in the seeds will be invalid and you'll have to reseed the database.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. i will copy over the key because i need the same resources. The second part of my problem however isn't solved yet, because mamp & xamp still have some issues working together.